# Change colour of blue panel on Azure API Management Developer Portal

Tags: azure-api-management

I am customising the look of the Azure API Management - Developer Portal using the Styles and Template features available in the Developer Portal when you login as an Administrator.

Using "Styles | Select an element on the page" I have edited the styles for a number of elements but I cannot edit the large blue box in the middle of the page.  When I select the element I do not get the real element.

Any suggestions on how to edit this element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I successfully changed the color and content here:

- APIM Publisher Portal / Widgets
- select layer "Home"
- click on "Banner" in "Featured"
- change Body(HTML)

Comment: Is there a way we could do it using azure arm templates?